# Display node with mixed languages

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, i18n-l10n

My nodes, with entity translation enabled, need to be able to handle a node where the content of the node is displayed differently regarding the labels and menus.

Let's say I am on a french page, displaying a list of all nodes, translated into french or not. If I click on a non-translated projects url I need the node to be displayed in a french environment (menus and labels in french) but displaying the node in its original language.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less the default behavior, depending on your Languages Detection and selection configuration.

In Drupal 7 every translation of a node is a new node, with its own node ID. So when you call for that node it will be displayed (call it by node/[nid] or a path alias).

Interface language (menus etc) is calculated separately from content, by the Detection and selection settings (`/admin/config/regional/language/configure`).

The most common setting is to only enable the `URL` Detection method and configure your default language not to use the `Path prefix language code` or `Language domain` and set one for all the other languages.

This way if you have an English node and you want to open it with a French interface the link should be constructed as:

`/fr/node/[englishID]`

or

`/fr/[french-path]/[english-title-pattern]`

So whatever method you're using to display node lists you have to adjust their URLs output to follow that logic.

Comment: Perfect, that seems to work as wished